# Using my train pass in Korea

Tags: trains, tickets, south-korea, train-stations

I'm going to South Korea for 2 weeks between September 10 and 24. I bought a flexible pass on the Korail website. But I discovered too late that I can only make reservations up to one month before any train trip.

My first train is on the September 18, so I cannot reserve a seat online. Can I do it in train stations in Korea? Or does the "one month before" rule also apply?

Answer (score 2):

Your Korail Pass is a ticket already valid for travel on any Korail train in Korea (although a seat is not guaranteed!), so I presume you are asking about **reservations**.

There are less than 30 days to go until September 10, so you can already make reservations online.  You can also make them at train stations, both in advance and on the day of travel.

In my experience, outside peak holiday periods, there is no need to make reservations in advance, just arrive at the train station a bit early -- or for frequent services like the Seoul-Busan KTX, you can just get the next train.

Comment: In addition, you can often get a "standing seat", that is between two cars. If your travel is short, I find it acceptable. (Seoul - Busan is about 3 hours by KTX)